# How to go to next line(results sheet) in this code ? vertical to horizontal transpose

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub Test2()

    Dim i&, j&, vIn, vOut

    With ThisWorkbook

        vIn = .Worksheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value2

        ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(vIn, 2), 1 To UBound(vIn, 1))

        For i = 1 To UBound(vIn, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(vIn, 2)
                vOut(j, i) = vIn(i, j)
            Next
        Next

        .Worksheets(2).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), UBound(vOut, 2)) = vOut

    End With
End Sub
```

Problem - Not able to go to next line if i run the program for the next set of data to be transposed.

[image: Check the image here]

Comment: Actually I don't get what the issue is? Are you trying to find the next empty line? `NextFreeRow = .Worksheets(2).Cells(.Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` is the next free row in column A.

Comment: I have to enter new set of data , but it over writes previous data. it's not being entered into the next line. please help me out

Comment: Also, this initial code of yours isn't functional in the code which i have .

Comment: After you find the next row as @Pᴇʜ suggested, you have to use `.Worksheets(2).Range("a" & NextFreeRow ).Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), UBound(vOut, 2)) = vOut` to write to that row

Comment: You ask questions only to get answers, not to accept them, right @Amit Shah?

Comment: @SIM Nothing Like that sir.
 Apologies,i  was occupied with some home emergency.
Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.

Comment: @SIM I just realised that the Web scraping question asked was closed , hence i couldn't reach to you.
I have posted a new feed with same question but a little complicated, could you have a look.@SIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you always write into `Range("a1")` when using this line

```
.Worksheets(2).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), UBound(vOut, 2)) = vOut
```

Instead first find the next free row

```
Dim NextFreeRow As Long
NextFreeRow = .Worksheets(2).Cells(.Worksheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

and then use this row as starting point

```
.Worksheets(2).Cells(NextFreeRow, "A").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), UBound(vOut, 2)) = vOut
```

---

Actually you might want to have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.Transpose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.transpose). This would be much easier to transpose the data.

Comment: It's working but then, the whole data along with header is being copied everytime

Comment: @AmitShah Then just don't copy the header but just the data?

Comment: The following "current Region" alternative please , if i use the range.copy, it ain't yielding anything.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only `Range(B2:B5")` or similar everytime then you you do not need to use an array for this. It is an overkill for this situation. You can use `Copy | PasteSpecial - Transpose` to achieve what you want. Also avoid using `Worksheets(1)`, `Worksheets(2)`. Use their code names or the sheet names. Using Index number can give you undesired results if the position of the sheet moves.

Is this what you are trying? (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsIn As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change the sheet names as applicable
    Set wsIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With wsOut
        '~~> Find next available row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        '~~> Copy relevant range
        wsIn.Range("B2:B5").Copy

        '~~> Write to relevant area
        .Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```